# git clone and push command hang，get no response by ssh

Tags: ssh, gerrit, freeze

our local gerrit version is gerrit-2.12.3.

It have be used for 4 years.It occured this issue suddenly.

when this issue orrured,someone can not clone and push by ssh, someone is ok.

all can clone and push by http.

when git push command execute,i have see the gerrit server have ssh connect 
established.

but can not push success,just hang.have no error.

how can i resovle this,thank you

Answer (score 0):

There could be any issues(repo size large ,more connections then thread) which is causing this problem, i would suggest you to come-up with the exact problem
 Read  this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/b0bMdq69KL4

Comment: my ssh config is like this

[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
        maxConnectionsPerUser = 0
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

my ssh config is like this

`[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
        maxConnectionsPerUser = 0`

when ssh frezze,gerrit server ssh connect condition is like this

`root@hkr-209:/home/mo/soft/gerrit2/git# netstat -tulanp | grep 29418
tcp6       0      0 :::29418                :::*                    LISTEN      7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:42112      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60180      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:45036     ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:3061       ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60188      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60564      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0  33280 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60179      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60185      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60487      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47982     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0    408 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47992     ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:42108      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60501      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47524     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.56.53.14:57179       ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0  33280 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60181      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60485      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60486      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47678     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.71:55037      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60307      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47988     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:42114      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60255      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47730     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.142.161:47812     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60183      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60189      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:63691      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60484      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60504      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:59970      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60190      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0      0 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60563      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi
tcp6       0  33280 10.10.142.183:29418     10.10.196.73:60182      ESTABLISHED 7071/GerritCodeRevi`

i dont know why so many connecttion do not finish.

and we do not have big repo so

our server has four cpus,so how many maxConnectionsPerUser does i need to config?